# Issue with php/mysql prepared insert statement

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I might just be too dumb to see it but here is my issue:

Code:

```
$stmt = $mysql->prepare("INSERT INTO projects_files (mid,filename,type) VALUES ('?','?','?')");
$stmt->bind_param('isi',$this->id,$File->filename,$File->type);
```

Error:

```
Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement
```

I have checked that all vars are assigned and have a value and the datatypes are all right.

Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put the question marks in quotes.  The database will quote everything appropriately.

```
$stmt = $mysql->prepare("INSERT INTO projects_files (mid,filename,type) VALUES (?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param('isi',$this->id,$File->filename,$File->type);
```

Comment: My friend just showed up and told me the same :) Thanks for the help tho.

Comment: @Jenjen1324 Mark the question as answered if you've solved your problem.

Comment: I was going to but you answered so fast I had to wait another 12 minutes ;)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `bindparam` single quotes(`'`) around the question mark(`?`)

```
$stmt = $mysql->prepare("INSERT INTO 
                     projects_files (mid,filename,type) 
                     VALUES (?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param('isi',$this->id,$File->filename,$File->type);
```

Comment: "isi" is the `types` parameter.  See http://us2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: @CullyLarson : Oho, I forgot that sorry. Thank for your advice. I updated my answer.